# Best way to use as little memory as possible when reading/writing large file?

Tags: java, android

I'm on mobile (android), and have a large text file, about 50mb. I want to be able to open the file and seek to a particular position, then start reading data into a buffer from that point. Is using FileReader + BufferedReader the best way to do this if I want to use as little memory as possible?:

```
BufferedReader in
    = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
in.skip(byteCount); // in some cases I have to read from an offset
// start reading a line at a time here
```

I'll also need to write to the file, only ever appending data, so:

```
FileWriter w = new FileWriter("foo.txt", true);
w.write(someCharacters);
```

I'm primarily interested to know if by misusing the wrong file reader/writer classes, I may accidentally be loading the entire file contents into memory before the reads or writes,

Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you only decide to keep something in memory if you think you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't want to read the whole file, but just a certain portion of it. In this case use [java.io.RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead:

1. its [seek()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method is guaranteed to do seek instead of reading & discarding (which is what some implementations of InputStream.skip() actually do)
2. the seek() method can move back the file pointer - something you can't do for an InputStream
3. a [getFilePointer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getFilePointer%28%29) method is provided to get the current position in file.
4. it only reads what you tells it to read, so there's no fear you'll accidentally load more than what you want

My dictionary app uses RandomAccessFile to access about 45MB of data back when each Android app could only use 16MB of RAM, also a service running my dictionary engine that operates on the same 45MB of data uses only about 2MB of RAM(and most of it prob were used by Davlik VM and not my search engine). So this class definitely works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a memory mapped file ([`java.nio.channels.FileChannel.map()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29)).  I'm not sure how much heap space would be allocated for this though.